Filament send Notification in console (save on database)
In my project, I have students and should notify them when their subscription ends. But Filament or Laravel Notification didn't support this or I didn't find it. I want to save notifications and Notify them when the subscription date approaches. Or is there any method when student come to their profile/panel notification should open?

If I am understanding the question correctly, you would like to notify students when their subscription is close to ending, and each student could have a different end date. What you could do is create a daily cron that finds the students whose subscription is ending today.
Once you have identified a student, do what you need to do in order to have a reference to the relevant User model (it needs to use the Notifiable trait). Then you can send the user a notification that will show up under the "bell" icon on the Filament panel by calling $user->notify() and providing it a Filament/Notifications/Notification as an argument.
Here is what the code would look like:
$user->notify(
    Notification::make()
        ->title('<insert_notification_text_here>')
        ->toDatabase()
);


Thank you, That's all I know but I want to notify users without cron. just before they come into their profile, Cron requires too many resources and every day isn't enough. Notifiable is already used.
